# why doesn't boolean value change?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function myFunction() {
    let myVar = true;
    if (myVar === true) {
      myVar = false;
      console.log("hello");
    }
    else if (myVar === false) {
      console.log("hi");
      myVar = true;
    }
    }

    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

```html
<button id="button">click me</button>
```

**what i expect** :

when function is executed, it will say "hello" because `myVar` is `true`, and when i run the function the second time it should be saying "hi" because `myVar` is changed to `false`

**result of code** :

when function is executed, it says "hello", but when i run it the second time, it still says "hello" and `myVar` doesn't change to `false`

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: When the function is run a second time it "creates" a new `let  myVar = true`. The value from the previous invocation does not matter / no longer exist anywhere.

Comment: Move the let myVar up and out of the function's scope, it will make it global and won't recall. With that said spend some time learning scope, it'll make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code is you re-declare the variable `myVar` to `true` everytime you run the function because its in the function scope

A solution is to put the variable `myVar` outside the function scope like this code below :

```js
  let myVar = true;

    function myFunction() {
    if (myVar === true) {
      myVar = false;
      console.log("hello");
    }
    else if (myVar === false) {
      myVar = true;
      console.log("hi");
    }
    }

    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

```html
<button id="button">click me</button>
```